# NET VIEW [Windows]

Tags: powershell, cmd, wmi

I am trying to get the share files from servers into a .txt, by using `net view \\server_name /all` command on the cmd gives me what I want , but there are several hundred servers, can I do this using a `batch file` or I could use `net view` on a `.txt` file with all servers listed on it.

I came across this code but it is again for a single server, can it be modified to be used for a `.txt` file

```
# List the file shares on the remote server: SERVER64.

$shares = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername SERVER64 -filter "Type=0"
$shares | foreach {
    $path=($_.path)
    $Description=($_.Description)
    $name=($_.name)
    $Caption=($_.Caption)

    "Share Name   : $name
     Source Folder: $path 
     Description  : $Description
     Caption : $Caption"
    }
```

Comment: Yes... Just add a `foreach` loop at the top.

Comment: Wow. You only tagged this question with three different scripting languages. Why not throw in R, Python and Perl as well.

Comment: @Squashman I tagged it with the languages I know, that way I could understand and do what I intend to, rather than tagging languages I am not familiar in!  Else those would be on the list too!  Its just a guy trying to figure out to get a work done and asking for help... so "thank you" for your "advice"

Comment: The purpose of SO is to provide a platform for people to ask questions about *specific* problems they have with implementing something. That usually implies that they already picked a language and implemented some code in that language. Hence it's normally expected that a question has only one language tag (the one used for the code you're having trouble with), not several different ones. Questions about which language to pick for implementing something are off topic in most cases, as they tend to be primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with lit, but here a script along your sample with a `[PSCustomObject]`

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\25\SO_52991906.ps1

$ServerShares = ForEach ($Server in (Get-Content .\Servers.txt)){
  ForEach ($Share in (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Computername $Server -filter "Type=0"|
                      Select-Object Name,Path,Description,Caption)){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server          = $Server
            'Share Name'    = $Share.Name
            'Source Folder' = $Share.Path
            Description     = $Share.Description
            Caption         = $Share.Caption
        }
    }
}
$ServerShares | Format-Table -auto
#$ServerShares | Out-GridView
#$ServerShares | Export-Csv .\ServerShares.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\25\SO_52991906.ps1

Server   Share Name Source Folder                     Description      Caption
------   ---------- -------------                     -----------      -------
ServX    C          C:\                               System           System
ServX    D          D:\                               Daten            Daten
ServX    G          G:\                                                G
ServX    H          H:\                                                H
ServX    print$     C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers Druckertreiber   Druckertreiber
ServX    LotPings   D:\Home\LotPings                                   LotPings
ServX    Users      C:\Users                                           Users
ServX    Virtual    D:\Virtual                                         Virtual
ServX    Winstall   D:\Winstall                                        Winstall
ServX    X          X:\                                                X
ServX    Y$         Y:\                               Standardfreigabe Standardfreigabe
ServX    Z$         Z:\                               Standardfreigabe Standardfreigabe
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-ComputerName` parameter accepts an array of names. It is known from `help Get-WmiObject -full` by the `[-ComputerName <String[]>]` parameter.

```
$computers = @('SERVER64', 'SERVER65', 'SERVER66')
$shares = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername $computers -filter "Type=0"
```

This will add a PSComputerName member to the output.

Microsoft has said that CIM is the future.

```
$shares = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Share -ComputerName $computers -Filter "Type=0"
```